# Best way to set if build necessary in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I trying to implement CD for development environment with GitHub Actions.

Common trigger to build application is a merged Pull Request into `develop`/`main` branches. But I have multiple development environments and want to allow developers update it only by simple commits to any personal branch.

But not every commit needs building (that may be only documentation update for example). So I trying to figure out best way to determine if build necessary.

Now I plan to determine to do build or not by commit message contents. If it starts with `#b-[environment name]` build should be happen.

```yaml
name: Build me

on:
  push:
    # ignore common branches and run build only when personal branch is changed
    branches-ignore:    
      - 'main'
      - 'develop'

jobs:
  build_app:
    name: Build latest app
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ startsWith(github.event.head_commit.message, '#b-') }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      ...
```

But in this case unnecessary information will be included in commit message and that makes history little bit dirty.

Also I know that is possible to exclude exact non-code [paths](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-excluding-paths):

```yaml
on:
  push:
    paths-ignore:
      - 'docs/**'
```

But I don't want to run build in case when only comments inside **code** is updated.

Also as I know it is possible to avoid builds by tags and labels. Can it be used for my purposes?

Comment: Put `[skip ci]` in the message on commits you don't want a build for. This is supported by many CI providers [including GHA](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-02-08-github-actions-skip-pull-request-and-push-workflows-with-skip-ci/). If you end up running CI on a few commits you didn't strictly need to, so what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did it like:

```yaml
---

name: "Build app"

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
    types:
      - closed
  push:
    branches:
      # environment names able for select to build application
      - environment_name_1/**
      - environment_name_2/**
      - environment_name_3/**
    # run build only if Python source files changed
    paths:
      - src/**.py

env:
  IAM_ROLE_NAME: github-actions-role
  AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: 12345678
  AWS_REGION: us-east-1
  LOG_DIR: /tmp/logs

jobs:
  build:
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged }} || ${{ github.ref_name }} != 'develop'
    name: "Build app"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
    steps:

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::${{ env.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}:role/${{ env.IAM_ROLE_NAME}}
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
          role-session-name: github-runner

      - name: Get env name to apply
        run: |
          # get environment name to deploy app inside it
          ENV_NAME=$(python -c 'print("${{ github.ref_name }}".split("/")[0])')
          if [ "${ENV_NAME}x" = "developx" ]; then
            # if branch name is "develop" staging environment should be used
            ENV_NAME="staging_environment"
          fi

          # check if ENV_NAME exists at AWS ...

          if [ "${EXISTS}x" = "1x" ]; then
            # add environment name to global ENVs to be able use it at next steps
            echo "ENV_APPLY=${ENV_NAME}" >> "${GITHUB_ENV}"
          else
            echo "ENV_APPLY=" >> "${GITHUB_ENV}"
            echo "No running environments with name: \`${ENV_NAME}\`" >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"
          fi

      - name: Checkout
        if: ${{ env.ENV_APPLY }}
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: "[${{ env.ENV_APPLY }}] build app"
        if: ${{ env.ENV_APPLY }}
        run: |
          # Build process here ...

      - name: Save logs
        if: ${{ env.ENV_APPLY }}
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: logs
          path: ${{ env.LOG_DIR }}
          retention-days: 31
```

And now we able choose environment for build app by changing git branch name (which should be `environment_name_X/some_feature`). Built-in feature [`[no ci]`](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-02-08-github-actions-skip-pull-request-and-push-workflows-with-skip-ci/) is using to be able skip builds